Link table to table or dashboard with dashboard in Apache Superset
When I click on table's row, I want it to fill in the other table with only the table's selected row's details. Is it possible to do in Superset? If yes, how?
I tried cross filtering and drill to detail. But, I need to link a selected record. How to do that dynamically?
